# Using contain in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a model that looks like this:

```
Performance
    - Location
    - Event
        - Location (Another one)
        - A bunch of other stuff
```

When I set the recursiveness to 2 I get *way* too much data (the "a bunch of other stuff")
When I use contain('Location') I only get the "Location" model directly under Performance, not under Event...

How do I get that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried (Assuming from controller):

```
$this->Performance->find('all', array(
   'contain' => array('Event' => 'Location')
));
```